# What is the usage of word "like" here?

Tags: word-usage

> Indian elephants are the main contributors to the biogas production,
>   but other vegetarian animals, *like* giraffes and rhinoceroses, help as
>   well.

What is the name of usage of this word "like" called, and is it possible to alternate this word with another word like "as" or "for example"?

Comment: Can I use "for example" like this: ".....animals, for example, giraffes and rhinoceroses, help as well.

Comment: Or should it be this? ".....animals, giraffes and rhinoceroses for example, help as well.

Comment: Both of them are ok? I know that you said "such as" is much better, but I don't know if you said the  " animals, for example, giraffes and rhinoceroses," is correct, or "animals, giraffes and rhinos for example" is correct.

Comment: Is that because "giraffes and rhinoceroses" modify "other vegetarian animals"? I know that you repeated that such as would fit better, but I am just curious.

Comment: Is it also possible: If the need arises, being unable to do this and that for example, you should do it. And this: If the need arises,such as being unable to do this and that, you should do it. The reason I am asking is because "such as being" is not connected to need but blocked by arises.

Answer (score 2):

'like' is a preposition meaning 'for example' here. So yes, you can use 'for example' if you want but 'like' does sound better in your example. Instead of 'like', you could also use 'such as' but you need to be aware that there is a subtle difference between the two. 'like' implies comparison. For example, "Dan enjoys watching shows like Modern Family" implies that Dan likes shows that are similar to Modern Family, but not necessarily Modern Family. 'such as' implies inclusion. When we replace 'like' with 'such as' and say "Dan enjoys watching shows such as Modern Family", we state that Dan enjoys watching "Modern Family" among other shows.